# VueJS how to prevent all anchors with # values to reload

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have `<a href='#section'>` html injected on a div.

```
<div v-html="content"></div>
```

Every time the anchor is click, the page reload.

How can I prevent this from reload but still redirects to the section.

Thank you

Comment: That does not sound like expected behavior: clicking on an anchor element with `#...` should not reload the page, unless you've got some other logic or scripts that are modifying that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<a href="#section" @click="$event.preventDefault()">`

Comment: `@click.prevent=""` is baked-in into Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Updated` hook to your component. In that hook create a new on click handler and call `event.preventDefault()`

Something like:

```
{
    Updated: () => {
       document.querySelectorAll("div a[href='#']").addEventListener("click", event => event.preventDefault())
    }
}
```